# Menu Bar Issues with Eclipse Java ADT on Ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, adt

I have downloaded the **Android SDK** from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) .

**OS version: Ubuntu 13.0 on 32 bit**

When I open **Eclipse**, its menu bar is not accessible or basically **not responding to clicks**. However, shortcuts to interact with menus seem to work fine (i.e.: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> etc).

I have tried the solutions mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361040/eclipse-menus-are-cut-off-or-dont-show) but it doesn't solve the problem, although it works fine when I run from terminal.

Comment: May I ask you how do you launch Eclipse, if not using the terminal? Because... the solutions featured in the link you gave us are indeed working.

Comment: I unzipped the SDK onto the desktop and navigated to eclipse folder and clicked on eclipse.exe file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it using the following code,

```
sudo su
echo "export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0" > /etc/X11/Xsession.d/81ubuntumenuproxy
```

**source:[Disable the appmenu in Ubuntu](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/disable-appmenu-global-menu-in-ubuntu.html)**

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to switch your current desktop environment to some other like KDE, cinnamon, Gnome classic etc etc.

I faced such issue when using GNOME/Unity desktop environment.

Refer [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available) and [this one](http://theswitchtolinux.blogspot.in/2012/11/install-multiple-desktop-environments.html)